# Colspan not working as expected (without CSS)

Tags: html, html-table

I'm doing a project and I can't use CSS at the moment.
I want to do a table with 3 columns and 3 rows, in this way:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf0KT.png)
. So as you can see the A cell needs to have colspan="2" and rowspan="2".
This is the code I used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table HTML</title>
    <style>
      table, tr, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
      tr, th, td {padding: 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">F</td>
          <td colspan="2">G</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the A cell isn't in 2 rows, the same for F and G
How I can fit all the cells in the right way?

I found the solution with CSS width property, in this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tabella HTML</title>
    <style>
      table, tr, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
      tr, th, td {padding: 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="width:50%">F</td>
          <td colspan="2" style="width:50%">G</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But for this project I can't use CSS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People old enough (or creating HTML emails up to these days) still remember the good old `width` HTML attribute :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Table HTML</title>
  <style>
    table,
    tr,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    tr,
    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" width="100">F</td>
      <td colspan="2" width="100">G</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I always used CSS for these things :)